# Keeps on "Launching : Launching delegate ... "

Tags: bada

I just start to try out my Hello World app development on Bada. I installed the SDK 1.0.0 on Windows XP (VM on Mac OS X).

In my Hello World app, I only add a Form and modified OnAppInitializing function and OnForeground function.

I tried both Run and Debug. The simulator is launched and running fine. But the progress of my Hello World is always 78% ~ 82% with "Launching : Launching delegate ..." The Hello World app is not shown on screen.

Any hint ?

Comment: what happens if you try to launch an SDK app ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalled SDK and it works fine now.